# I am getting Error in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, ssl-certificate

Hi All I am new to Jmeter and while recording the HTTPS request getting error in response data.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please, show us your code so that people can help you.

Comment: Have you tried to google your question? The first result seems very, very similar... [StackOverflow Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28958514/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-received-fatal-alert-unknown-ca)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the Certificate (ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt) to the trusted root folders of your browsers. Becuase Jmeter presents it's own certificate by being a proxy while you are recording, you need to tell your browser that this certificate is a trusted one.